# Des Englisch(s) Genitiv

Tags: word-usage, usage, genitive, style

Duden gibt zwei Genitive des Substantivs [Englisch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Englisch) an:

1. des Englisch
2. des Englischs

Welcher wird unter welchen Umständen verwendet?

Comment: Ich schreibe nur einen Kommentar, weil es deine Frage nicht beantwortet. Aber sowohl 1. also auch 2. hören sich für mich nicht richtig an, es sollte ein „3. des Englischen“ geben. Er ist des Englischen mächtig.

Comment: @Philipp: Wie ein Kollege (und DWDS) anmerkte gitb es "das Englisch" mit den beiden genannten Genitiven und das "das Englische" mit dem von dir genannten Genitiv. Was wann wie benutzt wird ... ist keine schlechte Frage.

Comment: @Philipp „Des Englischen“ ist der Genitiv von „das Englische“; um dieses Wort geht's uns hier gar nicht.

Comment: @a_donda Ja, danke ihr beide, mir ist schon klar, das das Substantiv eine andere Grundform hat. Daher ja auch nur der Kommentar ;)

Answer (score 1):

Das betrifft alle Namen von Sprachen oder Unterrichts- bzw. Studienfächern, die auf *-isch* enden (Kirgisisch, Französisch, Russisch, Arabisch, ...), hier dargestellt am Beispiel *Englisch*:

Es gibt zwei Formen des Substantivs:

1. (das) Englisch
2. das Englische

Die Form 2 kann nur gemeinsam mit einem bestimmten Artikel verwendet werden, die Form 1 wird entweder ohne Artikel oder mit einem bestimmten Artikel verwendet. Beide Formen kommen nur im Singular vor (es gibt keinen Plural.)

Davon ist zu unterscheiden das substantivierte Adjektiv, das nicht nur auf Sprache und Unterrichtsfächer beschränkt ist:

3. der, die, das, eine Englische, ein Englischer, ein Englisches

Beispiele:

> 1 Jürgen spricht Englisch.
> 1 Das Englisch von Jürgen ist schlecht.
>
> 2 Das Englische ist mit dem Deutschen verwandt.

> 3 Der Englische besteht aus Rostbraten, Beiried und dem Rindslungenbraten.

---

**Die Form 1 wird wie folgt dekliniert:**

- Nominativ

  > **Das Englisch** von Anita klingt sehr schön.
  > **Englisch** ist mit Deutsch verwandt.
- Genitiv

  - von einem Verb regiertes Genitivobjekt

    > Oliver *bedient* sich **des Englisch**, das er in der Schule gelernt hat.
    > Oliver *bedient* sich **des Englischs**, das er in der Schule gelernt hat.
  - Präpositionalobjekt mit Genitiv

    > Simon entziffert die Inschrift *mithilfe **seines Englisch.***
  - Genitivattribut innerhalb einer Nominalgruppe

    > *Die Aussprache **des Englisch*** ist schwierig.
- Dativ

  > **Im Englisch** des 16. Jahrhundert gab es noch eine Du-Sie-Unterscheidung.
  > Deutsch ist mit **Englisch** verwandt.
- Akkusativ

  > Eugene spricht **Englisch.**
  > Ich will **das Englisch** von Martin gar nicht hören.

---

**Deklination der Form 2:**

- Nominativ

  > **Das Englische** ist mit dem Deutschen verwandt.
- Genitiv

  - von einem Verb regiertes Genitivobjekt

    > Es *bedarf* **des Englischen** um diesen Text zu verstehen.
  - Präpositionalobjekt mit Genitiv

    > Margit verständigt sich mit Simon *mithilfe **des Englischen.***
  - Genitivattribut innerhalb einer Nominalgruppe

    > *Die Entwicklung **des Englischen*** aus dem Urgermanischen ist gut erforscht.
- Dativ

  > Nominalklassen fehlen **dem Englischen.**
- Akkusativ

  > Andere Sprachen beeinflussen **das Englische.**

---

Die Entscheidung, wann welche der beiden Formen zu verwenden ist, und wann im Fall der Form 1 im Genitiv die Variante mit oder ohne S Anwendung finden soll, finde ich recht schwierig zu begründen. Hier ist ein Versuch:

Wenn die individuelle Art und Weise der Verwendung einer Sprache durch einen bestimmen Sprechers gemeint ist, ist die Form 1 mit Artikel (oder einem anderen [Determinativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart))) vorzuziehen. Ebenfalls wird die Form 1 mit Artikel bevorzugt, wenn eine Variante der Sprache gemeint ist.

> (Nom) **Das Englisch** von Anita klingt sehr schön.
> (Gen) Simon entziffert die Inschrift mithilfe **seines Englisch.**
> (Akk) Ich will **das Englisch** von Martin gar nicht hören.

> (Dat) **Im Englisch** des 16. Jahrhundert gab es noch eine Du-Sie-Unterscheidung.

Wenn die Sprache als allgemeines Kommunikationsmittel gemeint ist, verwendet man entweder die Form 2 oder die Form 1 ohne Artikel:

> (Nom) **Das Englische** ist mit dem Deutschen verwandt.
> (Dat) Das Deutsche ist mit **dem Englischen** verwandt.
> (Akk) Andere Sprachen beeinflussen **das Englische.**

> (Nom) **Englisch** ist mit Deutsch verwandt.

Das trifft auch auf den Genitiv zu:

> Christa bedient sich **ihres Englisch.**
> Simon entziffert die Inschrift mithilfe **seines Englisch.**

> Die Entwicklung **des Englischen** aus dem Urgermanischen ist gut erforscht.

---

Bleibt noch zu klären, wann die Form 1 im Genitiv mit S und wann ohne S zu verwenden ist. Auch dazu habe ich keine exakte Antwort, aber ich glaube, dass aus grammatischer Sicht beide Varianten gleichwertig sind. Die Sprachökonomie spricht aber dafür, das S am Ende eher wegzulassen, weil zwei Zischlaute hintereinander für viele schwierig auszusprechen sind. Meiner persönlichen Beobachtung nach folgt der aktuelle Trend des Sprachwandels auch genau dieser Idee. Mir scheint, als wäre die Form mit S immer schon die zweite Wahl gewesen, aber heute drängt die S-lose Form die Form mit S noch mehr in den Hintergrund.

Comment: Ich habe zwei Kommata hinzugefügt (in „Oliver *bedient* sich **des Englischs** das er in der Schule gelernt hat“ u.ä.) Wenn die überflüssig sind, dann bitte die ursprüngliche Antwort zurücksetzen.

Comment: Zu „Bleibt noch zu klären, wann die Form 1 im Genitiv mit S und wann ohne S zu verwenden ist.“: Genau das war die Frage; der Ausführungen zu den Formen 2 und 3 sind für die Frage irrelevant. Du nahmst *die Unterscheidung zwischen Genitivobjekten eines Verbs einerseits und Genitivattributten einer Nominalgruppe und Prapositionalgruppen andererseits* im Hinblick auf den Suffix S. Das hilft schon mal. Wie sicher bist du dir in diesem Punkt? Danke!!!

Comment: Gegenbeispiel zu deiner These (individuelle Art und Weise der Verwendung einer Sprache durch einen bestimmen Sprecher = Form 1): Er ist des Englischen mächtig.

Comment: @Philipp: Ich weiß, das meine These auf wackligen Beinen steht. Hast du einen belastbareren Ansatz?

Answer (score 0):

Beide Formen mögen sprachlich korrekt sein, allerdings sind beide sehr selten. Der Genitiv des substantivierten Adjektivs wird um Größenordnungen häufiger verwendet.

"Des Englischs" wird in der Realität praktisch nicht verwendet, wohl weil die Aussprache recht mühsam für die meisten Muttersprachler ist. Ich selbst tue mich jedenfalls schwer damit. Es erfordert Konzentration auf die Aussprache, weil s nach Zischlauten eher untypisch für die deutsche Sprache ist.

Hier ein [Google-Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=des+Englisch%2Cdes+Englischs%2Cdes+Englischen&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=0&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdes%20Englisch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdes%20Englischen%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Google Ngram]

In der Darstellung fehlt "des Englischs", weil es im Textkorpus nicht gefunden wird.

Answer (score -2):

Ganz ehrlich, ich glaube, dass ich die erste Form noch nie verwendet habe. [Genitive enden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Genitiv-auf-s-oder-es) klassischerweise auf -s oder auf -es und die erste Form klingt echt merkwürdig.

Edit: „Als Grund für die Schwankung [hinsichtlich der Genitivmarkierung] wird angegeben, dass die Endungen zwecks Verständlichkeit für den Leser weggelassen werden können, da der Eigenname ohne Genitivendung besser erkannt werde.“ - https://grammatikfragen.de/showthread.php?1654-Genitiv-mit-s-oder-ohne-s

Meine Meinung: Ja, man kann die Eigennamen besser erkennen. „Die EU-Kandidatin erklärte die Friedensidee zur Triebfeder des Europa.“ Da weiß man genau, worauf sich der Satz bezieht. Ich bleibe aber dabei, dass das trotzdem sehr merkwürdig und ungewohnt klingt.

Comment: Ganz ehrlich: Ich würde den ersten Satz streichen. Was Du persönlich verwendest oder nicht ist hier nicht Thema, sondern was richtig ist. Evtl. noch, was gebräuchlich ist. Das Pathos des "Ganz ehrlich" wird auch nicht klar.

Comment: Im Ausgangspost wird die Frage gestellt, in welcher Situation welche Formulierung verwendet wird. Darauf gehst du nicht ein. Ich gebe daher hier -1.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht ganz, wie der letzte Absatz zur Beantwortung der gestellten Frage beitragen soll. Stackexchange ist kein Forum zu Äußerung persönlicher Meinungen. Es spricht nichts dagegen, sich als Muttersprachler ab und zu mal auf das persönliche Sprachgefühl zu berufen wenn man trotz gründlicher Recherche keine belastbaren Fakten gefunden hat, aber in diese Kategorie würde ich deinen letzten Absatz nicht einordnen (zumal er wie schon thematisiert nichts mit der Frage zu tun hat).